# Getting numbers from 1 to 4 in a random order

Tags: android, random

I want to get 4 random value(different from each other) 1 to 4 in Android.

I wrote a code like this. But the values aren't different from each other.

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int number, idSearch[]=new int[4];
    number = random.nextInt(4);
    idSearch[0] = number;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        number = (int) random.nextInt(4);
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (idSearch[j] == number) {
                number = random.nextInt(4);
            }

        }
        idSearch[i] = number;
    }
```

Where is error? Can you help me?

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem.  You aren't trying to get 4 random numbers, you're trying to get the numbers from 1-4 in a random order.

Comment: I'm sorry. I typed wrong. I'm trying to get the numbers from 1-4 in a random order.

Comment: `List<Integer> al = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  Collections.shuffle(al);
  System.out.println(al);`

Answer (score 2):

I reckon the easiest way of generating a `List<Integer>` with values from 1 to 4 (inclusive) in a random order would be to first create a `List<Integer>` with the initial values and shuffle it:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

Collections.shuffle(list);

System.out.println(list);

>> [4, 1, 3, 2]
```

Keep in mind that this list cannot be added to or removed from.

If you would like it to be mutable, simply pass it to the constructor of an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> mutableList = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Remember to import `java.util.*`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK1.8 then you can generate numbers from 1 to 4 in random order, you can use `new Random().ints()` as shown below:

```
int[] randoms = new Random().ints(1,5).distinct().limit(4).distinct().toArray();
```

If you are using JDK1.7 or earlier, you need to use [Collections.shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) rather than you re-inventing the shuffling the logic.

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the numbers from 1-4 in a random order.

Comment: Yes, it does the same

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Random.ints

Comment: You need JDK1.8 in which `ints()` has been added in `Random` class

Answer (score -1):

You have to create new object Random and pls use second for behind fist for.

Comment: The asker is already creating a new `Random` object. I think you mean a second `for` loop after the first `for` loop, but I’m not convinced that that will be enough to solve the issue.